# Select continue repeat occurrences within time period <x days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data.

```
KEY     |ERRRTYPE       |CREATEDATE |ERROR  
101aa   |Not on Target  |1/2/2019   |Y
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/2/2019   |Y
123ds   |Not on Target  |1/2/2019   |Y
101aa   |Not on Target  |1/3/2019   |Y
121kd   |Not on Target  |1/3/2019   |Y
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/3/2019   |Y
132ee   |Not on Target  |1/4/2019   |Y
123ww   |Not on Target  |1/4/2019   |Y
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/4/2019   |Y
123kk   |Not on Target  |1/4/2019   |Y
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/5/2019   |Y
101aa   |Not on Target  |1/5/2019   |Y
234ew   |Not on Target  |1/5/2019   |Y
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019   |Y
101aa   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019   |Y
124dd   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019   |Y
```

I need to find the pull the current or latest date records and as well as if the KEY field consecutively recurring in past 5 days or less then need to return Y in the new column,

following the data should look like:

```
KEY     |ERRRTYPE       |CREATEDATE     |ERROR  |Consecutive 
111bw   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019       |Y      | Y           
101aa   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019       |Y      | Y
124dd   |Not on Target  |1/6/2019       |Y      | N
```

Since the `KEYs = 111bw`repeated 5 times in row each day and KEY 101aa  repeated 2 times in a row, Consecutive Error field should have Y else its N

Answer (score 0):

following solution is prepared on SQL Server
I'm not sure if it works successfully on MySQL
Since all functions are standard SQL like [dense_rank](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/tsql-dense-rank-function.aspx), CTEs, etc, I hope there is a way to convert follow code to MySQL codes or it works as is

```
;with cte as (
    select
    *, dense_rank() over (order by createdate desc) rn
    from ErrorData
)
select
    [KEY], ERRRTYPE, CREATEDATE, ERROR,
case when t.cnt = 5 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Consecutive 
from cte
cross apply (
    select
    count(*) as cnt
    from ErrorData e
    where e.[KEY] = cte.[KEY]
    and e.createdate >= dateadd(dd, -5, cte.createdate)
) as t
where rn = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Eralper, THis works but I made a mistake. 101aa should also have 'Y' for Consecutive Error since 101aa appeared Consecutively on 1/6/2019  and 1/5/2019

Comment: For consecutive property, I thought 5 consecutive days is important. So 5 days is not a must, as I understand. Is it current day and previous days (at least one day)?

Answer (score 0):

what is the frequency of each key in a day? can the key repeat number of time in a day or it may occure once in a day

Comment: it does not repeat in a day